# Mongo regex with array of elements not accurate

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Document schema is as follows
`"events": [
        {
            "title": "title1"
        },
        {
            "title": "title2"
        },
        {
            "title": "title3"
        }
    ]`

I have requirement to search (regex ) in **events.title** field and get the only matching element/object from the array . For that i am querying like this ,

```
db.collection.find({ "$or" : [ { "events.title" : { "$regex" : ".*title2.*" , "$options" : "i"}} , { "events.title" : { "$regex" : ".*title5.*" , "$options" : "i"}}] , "events" : { "$elemMatch" : { "title" : { "$ne" :  null }}}},{"events.$":1,"_id":0});
```

I was expecting the result would be `{ "events" : [ { "title" : "title2"} ] }` , but it returns

```
{ "events" : [ { "title" : "title1"} ] }
```

How can i update the query so that only matching element in array is returned in result ?

**UPDATE**

```
"events": {
        $elemMatch: {
            "$or": [{
                "title": {
                    "$regex": ".*title2.*",
                    "$options": "i"
                }
            },
            {
                "title": {
                    "$regex": ".*title5.*",
                    "$options": "i"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
```

did the trick . Now it returns only matching element in the array irrespective of the position.

Thanks for the help

Comment: The `$` means the first element. You can do it with aggregation maybe but you can filter them after you get the result.

Comment: @AmiramKorach If there is no other solution i can filter the result again using drivers .

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
db.collection.find({events: {
                             $elemMatch: {
                                          title: {$in: [/.*title2.*/i,
                                                        /.*title5.*/i]
                                                 }
                                         }
                            }
                   },
                   {"events.$": 1, _id: 0});
```

Comment: This will still give him the first item. `$` means first.

Comment: That's right, it gives him the first item that matches the regex.

Comment: @AndriySimonov this still gives the first element . Is there any other way ?

Comment: @Mohammedshebin The question said `the only matching element/object from the array`. The query returns documents with the first matching array element. It looks exactly as you mentioned in the expected result. I assumed you need only one element. Do you actually need all matching array elements?

Comment: "events": {
        $elemMatch: {
            "$or": [{
                "title": {
                    "$regex": ".*title2.*",
                    "$options": "i"
                }
            },
            {
                "title": {
                    "$regex": ".*title5.*",
                    "$options": "i"
                }
            }]
        }
    }

This in projection did the trick . Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
{"events": {
        $elemMatch: {
            "$or": [{
                "title": {
                    "$regex": ".*title2.*",
                    "$options": "i"
                }
            },
            {
                "title": {
                    "$regex": ".*title5.*",
                    "$options": "i"
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

in projection did the trick . Now it returns only matching element in the array irrespective of the position